# Spring XD - UDP inside Jobs

Tags: mongodb, udp, spring-batch, spring-integration, spring-xd

I have been using Spring XD for a while for continuous ingestion of sensor data and it works perfectly.

The new requirement that I have is the ability to "replay" portions of that data. In my particular case it would be reading from MongoDB (with a certain query), generate a UDP packet with a certain filed of the entry and send it to a SocketAddress in a fixed interval of time.

The first attempt that I am implementing is through spring-batch job. The reader is simple since it is just querying MongoDB for the data, but I am concern about the UDP portion. It does not feel natural to use spring-batch for sending UDP packets, so I would like to know if anybody can suggest me an idea for implementing this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could use a custom XD source with a [MongoDB Inbound Channel Adapter](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/mongodb.html#mongodb-inbound-channel-adapter) piped to a custom sink using a [UDP Outbound Channel Adapter](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/ip.html#udp-adapters).

Comment: I have those, my problem is the replay concept. I want to be able to start/stop the replay of a portion of the data and the itemization of the entries.